# What's the correct way to set up an AJAX workflow response handler in an Aviarc screen?

Tags: ajax, handler, response, aviarc

Say I have a screen like this:

```xml
<screen>
    <button label="Foo" name="foo-button"/>

    <action:behaviors>
        <action:when widget-event="foo-button.onClick">
            <action:call-ajax-workflow name="ajax/do-lots-of-foo"/>
            <!-- (1) -->
            <action:call-ajax-workflow name="ajax/do-less-foo"/>
            <!-- (2) -->
        </action:when>

        <action:when system-event="onAjaxRequestCompleted">
            <!-- (3) -->
        </action:when>
    </action:behaviors>
</screen>
```

What is the correct place to put a handler for each AJAX request? Theoretically, I would assume that either (1) or (2) would be incorrect, as if the workflows are truly asynchronous then `ajax/do-less-foo` should return before `ajax/do-lots-of-foo`.

My instinct is to handle the responses at location (3), and conditionally execute different code based on the value of `event-parameters.workflow`.

Is this correct? Or is `call-ajax-workflow` actually blocking, and the commands in the `onClick` block are just executed serially?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, call-ajax-workflow does block the timeline it's running in while the call is happening. It doesn't block the screen or any other timelines.

In Aviarc 2, you could call an ajax workflow from script to have it non-blocking. I'm not sure whether this capability is still easily accessible in Aviarc 3 (presumably it is).

Handlers should currently be placed inline so that they're next to the code they're handling, or, if a handler should deal with multiple calls, it should be put into an action block with calls to said action block as inline handlers.

The onAjaxRequestCompleted event should only ever be bound to if there's something which needs to be done indiscriminately on returns from ajax calls.

If the command is ever changed to be (possibly) non-blocking, or if an additional command is added which is non-blocking, or so forth, I would expect that handlers would be addable as sub-elements of the command.